# How to get row values from DataGridView based on List

Tags: c#, datagridview, rows

I have a list newList.
Its contains a bunch of CSV headers, such as, DocID, DocName etc (which has been compiled by a bunch of checklist boxes that have been checked)

I now need the values from each row that match the checked Headers i.e. Headers in the list.

So lets say DocID and DocName has been checked and are in the list "newList".

I would then need to loop through to get all the values from the rows. But only the data with the checked headers.

```
row1String = 1234 Test1
```

I have tried to get all values using

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
    { 
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        string value = cell.Value.ToString();

    }
}
```

But this doesnt compile the values into a string.
I also tried StringBuilders but the output was just System.something

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<string> rowStringList = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{ 
    string rowString = "";
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn cell in row.Cells)
    {
        rowString += cell.Value.ToString();
    }
    rowStringList.Add(rowString );
}
```